# eslint-watch not running upon saving files with the .jsx extension

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I installed eslint-watch https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-watch so eslint would run every time I hit save. However, whenever I save a file with the extension .jsx the linter doesn't run. I'm confident this is the issue because the linter does run after i save a change to a non jsx file and it works if I change the .jsx file extension to .js.

I would really appreciate any help. Here are the relevant files.

package.json scripts (directory paths are correct)

```
"lint": "esw webpack.config.* babel.config.* src/**/*.js src/**/*.jsx server/**/*.js --color",
"lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
```

package.json dependencies (same versions in package-lock.json)

```
"eslint": "^6.2.1",
"eslint-watch": "^6.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
```

.eslintrc.js (in the root directory)

```
module.exports = {
  "root": true,
  "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "react"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules": {
    },
    "settings": {
      "react": {
        "version": "detect"
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all you have to do is add the `--ext .jsx` flag. This will tell eslint to look for jsx extensions on run. Even though in your config you have told it to parse jsx files and you've passed the glob pattern for jsx, eslint doesn't know it needs to look for or parse `.jsx` files.

If this doesn't resolve your issue create a ticket on the [repo's github page](https://github.com/rizowski/eslint-watch/issues/new) and I can assist further.